# Can you style the rubber/bounce/elastic scroll area present above the header/below the footer in OS X/iOS browsers?

Tags: ios, scroll, bounce, rubber

I've already searched a lot regarding this topic and it honestly seems impossible.

Which is a bummer, since being able to add some small details/artistic touch to this bland area would definitely be very welcome.

Unless I am mistaken and there is a way to do that - please, enlighten!

Comment: Do you mean in a web page, or in a `UIScrollView`?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik no, since it is provided by the app, not by the html code. All scrollviews have this behavior enabled by default.
However a image as backgroundcolor should be visible.